# Using Selenium to click one link and then back to main page and click other links

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I'm doing a web scraping I could fetch the information in one specific link but I want to automate the process by going to each item's link on that page and fetch information then come back to the main page then click to the following item's link.

the URL is: https://ca.iherb.com/c/Vitamins?noi=48

I want to click "California Gold Nutrition, Gold C, Vitamin C, 1,000 mg, 60 Veggie Capsules" item and then click the "View all Reviews" in the bottom. Then move back to the main page and click the following item's link.

I used this code to fetch all the items' links but then couldn't figure out to click to the "View all Reviews" within each link, then move back to main page:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_path)
driver.get('https://ca.iherb.com/c/Vitamins?noi=48')

x = [my_elem.get_attribute("href") for my_elem in driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='absolute-link-wrapper']/a")]
```

Please help to check pictures below for the illustration, thank you so much:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wg5XG.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kspuZ.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1pbyz.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try the same using requests module first and should go for selenium as a last resort. As you have started your script using selenium in the first place, I thought to come up with selenium oriented solution. Given that the following should work:

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://ca.iherb.com/c/Vitamins?noi=48")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

#close the pop up
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"svg[data-ga-event-action='list-close']"))).click()

#store all the links in a list
item_links = [item.get_attribute("href") for item in wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,".absolute-link-wrapper > a.product-link")))]

#iterate over the links
for item_link in item_links:
    driver.get(item_link)

    #locate and click on the `View All Reviews` link
    all_reviews_link = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"span.all-reviews-link > a")))
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();",all_reviews_link)
    time.sleep(5) #slow the script down
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! really appreciate it!

Comment: Can you show me how to get the link from "all_reviews_link" ?
because I want to automate the same structure to scrape the data from that link and then move on to other product's "all_reviews_link"

Comment: I'm not sure if this is what you meant `print(all_reviews_link.get_attribute("href"))`? Btw, if your question is different, try creating a new post and drop here the link. Thanks.

Comment: perfect! You have done it perfectly! thank you!

Answer (score 0):

My preference for this type of scraping would be a mix of Selenium and BeautifulSoup because there is less Javascript and could by-pass some of the clicking every single link using BeautifulSoup, therefore not much of need for Selenium for the initial part:

We can get all the hyperlinks in [this page](https://ca.iherb.com/c/Vitamins?noi=48) using this small piece of code.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://ca.iherb.com/c/Vitamins?noi=48'

html = requests.get(url).content

soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'lxml')

a_tags = soup.find_all('a', class_ = 'absolute-link product-link',href = True)
arr_url= []

for a in a_tags:

    arr_url.append(a['href'])
    print(a['href'])
```

Output :

[image]
You can save all these in an array and iterate through every one of it until you have scraped everything you want.

You can use then Selenium to click on 'View all Reviews' by directly opening these above hyperlinks.